# preserving datetime values in rails while saving in utc(default)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a a checkin:`datetime` field in `rails` and is using the default `utc`.

But the issue is that when the `user` submits the `form` the `checkin` date is coming with his `local timezone` info. So rails will automatically `convert` this to utc and depending on the difference with his timezone and utc there might be an off of one day.

So how can I `change` the `date` to `utc` without changing `values`?

**Update**

This is the only code I use for saving to database.(the utc conversion is done by activerecord(i think) if the passed in value is not utc)

```
   reservation=current_user.reservations.create(reservation_params)
   reservation.save
```

Comment: So you want to **ignore** the `local timezone` information, and just save the raw value? What are you doing currently? (Edit your post to include the code.)

Comment: @TomLord The checkin is for rooms and rooms are located in different time zones. But i think its too much headache to work with timezones and thought it would be easy to use the default utc. The form the user is submiting is an angular form with the javascript date object for the checkin date. So it will be based on the timezone of the user

Comment: For a start, surely you need to be using the timezone **of the room** rather than the timezone **of the user**. Otherwise, booking a room in a non-UTC timezone will give surprising results. And again, I repeat, please include the relevant code in your post.

Comment: @TomLord  I dont have custom code for changing to utc. I am just saving the values as recieved from user. Rails is doing the conversion to utc asits recieved in different timezone.  Any way am updating the saving part of the code. sorry for the confusion..

Comment: @TomLord I dont need the time part actually..The date is what am worried about. When showing the booked dates to the room owner am showing dates in utc itself without converting and not showing the time..

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to do that. It is not direct conversion as I expected but it works. I changed the form input field to sent a string with just the date and time(without utc).

```
eg: 2016-07-13 00:00:00
```

Then in my controller before saving I used below code to parse it to utc.
reservation.check_in= Time.zone.parse(value_from_view)

**example:**

```
reservation.check_in= Time.zone.parse('2016-07-13 00:00:00')
```

This returns `Wed, 13 Jul 2016 00:00:00 UTC +00:00` as expected.